# Replacing a word and fixing white spaces using

Tags: javascript

Hello there I am trying to Fix the whitespace characters in the sentence "This      sentence       has       too   many    spaces." so that there's only 1 space between each word (include all white spaces using \s).

Additionally, replace the word "has" with "had", but only the word itself, not parts of other words that might have the same string "has" in them.

```js
var sentence ="This      sentence       has       too   many    spaces."

function fixSentence(){
  sentence.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
  sentence.replace(/\bhas\b/i, "had");

  console.log(sentence);
}

fixSentence();
```

Comment: You didn't explain what problem you're having. That said, read the docs for [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), specifically the return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replace` method returns the modified string. It does not modify the original variable.

What you are trying to do is this:

```js
var sentence ="This      sentence       has       too   many    spaces."

function fixSentence(){
  sentence = sentence.replace(/  +/g, ' ');
  sentence = sentence.replace(/\bhas\b/i, "had");
  console.log(sentence);
}

fixSentence();
```

Comment: i am not able to edit the console.log part of the code as it is locked in the question. How do i get around this! thanks

Comment: @H.Ach I have modified my answer to hopefully what you are looking for.

Comment: it should stay as console.log(sentence) that part I cant edit. I can only edit the function part of this question :/

Comment: @H.Ach That should do it.